# How can I stop an infinite loop While True in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, smooth-scrolling

I want to parse the football odds from a website that uses JavaScript, so it doesn't download all the data in once and I have to use slow scrolling to load the rest of the page and then parse it.
I'm using a function I found on this website to scroll down the page, but the function creates an infinite loop and I don't know how to stop it and go on with my code.
I'd like that the scrolling stops when the page reached the part of web page I'm interested in and then goes on parsing the data.

I tried already making if statement ending with break but it didn't work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time
import pandas as pd

class wait_for_more_than_n_elements(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, count):
        self.locator = locator
        self.count = count

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            count = len(ec._find_elements(driver, self.locator))
            return count >= self.count
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

#Apri la pagina
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Applications/Python 3.7/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.eurobet.it/it/scommesse/?splash=false#!/calcio/it-serie-a/')
time.sleep(5)

# Doppia chance
dc_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('doppia chance')
dc_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

# Page source for changing page
source_dc = driver.page_source
soup_dc = BeautifulSoup(source_dc, 'lxml')

# Scrolling down the page
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.box-row-event:nth-child(7)")))

while True:
    results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("box-row-event")
    print("Results count: %d" % len(results))

    # scroll to the last element
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results[-1])

    # wait for more results to load
    wait.until(wait_for_more_than_n_elements((By.CLASS_NAME, 'box-row-event'), len(results)))
```

I expect that the loop ends when it reaches the last element in the variable results, but unfortunately it goes on with the loop and printing always the same length of the variable results.

Comment: Do you want to exit the loop once you reached certain number of results or once all the results are loaded? You have to use break or conditional check in while statement line.

Comment: That's too much code for a good question. Try to minimize the code (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Surprisingly often, you will find the solution to your issue yourself by doing so. If not, you will make your question much more attractive.

Comment: @supputuri I'd like to exit the loop when all the results are loaded.
I tried to use a break or conditional check but it didn't work. I probably used a wrong conditional check. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @pasbi I understand what you say, but this is the minimum code to reproduce the problem. I'll try to delete some part of the code to minimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many try outs I finally found out a solution that works for me:

```
last_count = len(results)
while True:
    results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("box-row-event")
    print("Results count: %d" % len(results))

    # scroll to the last element
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results[-1])
    time.sleep(1)

    # wait for more results to load
    wait.until(wait_for_more_than_n_elements((By.CLASS_NAME, 'box-row-event'), len(results)))
    wait.until(ec.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'box-row-event')))
    time.sleep(1)

    #new count
    new_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("box-row-event"))

    if new_count == last_count:
        break

    last_count = new_count
```

When the page goes to the last result and finally downloaded all the results the loop is going to break.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the below code to exit the loop.

```
results = 0
# loop until the number of results are equals to previous results
until results == len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("box-row-event")) :
    results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("box-row-event")
    print("Results count: %d" % len(results))

    # scroll to the last element
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results[-1])

    # wait for more results to load
    wait.until(wait_for_more_than_n_elements((By.CLASS_NAME, 'box-row-event'), len(results)))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but unfortunately your solution didn't work.
the line `until results == len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("box-row-event")) :` it is not recognized from python.